# How to install libqt5

Tags: qt

Trying to run rtklib on ubuntu 16.04.2 and getting this

```
$ ./rtkplot_qt: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing I need to install libqt5?  If so how to install it can someone give me some instruction?

Comment: Open the terminal and `sudo apt update` , after `sudo apt install libqt libqt5webenginewidgets5`

Comment: If OP really has 16.04, it does [not have `libqt5webenginewidgets5` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=names&keywords=libqt5webenginewidgets5). @lightscout, please edit you question with complete steps to reproduce and write where you got `rtklib`.